# Rendering Nested Objects in Reactjs

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I'm following a Meteor/Reactjs tutorial. I have a list of items we will call them apple, and a sublist of items called orange.

Each orange in the orange collection has a "appleId" field, which is mapped to the _id of the associated Apple.

Currently what I have doesn't work as I want. The ideal list should render as:

- Apple 1

  - Orange 1A
  - Orange 1B
- Apple 2

  - Orange 2A
  - Orange 2B

I use these functions:

```
renderApples() {
  return this.props.apples.map((apple) => (
    <Apple key = {apple._id} apple={apple) />
  ));
}
renderOranges() {
  return this.props.oranges.map((orange) => (
    <Orange key = {orange._id} orange={orange) />
  ));
}
```

And then call them in my main component like so:

```
render() {
  return (
  <div>
    <ul>
      {this.renderApples()}
    </ul>
    <ul>
      {this.renderOranges()}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

This obviously just renders all the Apples, and then all the Oranges but I have been having difficulty finding a clever way to render them as described above.

Comment: It seems like you don't have your data formatted correctly since I can't see how you would know what oranges are associated with which apples.

Answer (score 0):

if the data relationship is as you say, wouldn't it be the responsibility of the apple renderer to also render the oranges?

e.g.

```
renderApples() {
  return this.props.apples.map((apple) => (
    <Apple key={apple._id}
        apple={apple}
        oranges={Oranges.find({appleId: apple._id}).fetch()} />
  ));
}
```

update:

and then the Apple component would take care of display the oranges associated with each apple. e.g.

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

export class Apple extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    renderOranges() {
        return this.props.oranges.map((orange) => (
            <Orange key={orange._id} orange={orange} />
        ));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>I'm an Apple! {this.props.apple._id}</h1>
                <ul>
                    {this.renderOranges()}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Apple.propTypes = {
    apple: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    oranges: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};
```

Comment: This is largely what I thought, just was not sure how to shoehorn it into the renderer. Your solution makes sense, however it does not render the Orange objects when done this way unfortunately. I'll continue to investigate.

Comment: @NobodyInParticular, what does your Apple renderer look like now? you have to rewrite it to iterate over {this.props.oranges} and create the Orange renderers. i can't tell if you tried that or you thought that would happen automagically.

Comment: It looks like this currently:

    `renderApples() {
      return this.props.apples.map((apple) => (
        <Apple key={apple._id}
            apple={apple}
            oranges={Oranges.find({appleId: apple._id}).fetch()} />
      ));
    }`

Followed by:

    `<ul>
      { this.renderApples() }
    </ul>`

It's not that I thought it would happen automatically, I just can't figure out how you would iterate over the Oranges. It's just a nested for loop but syntactically I've had little success.

Comment: @NobodyInParticular, i updated my answer to show an example of an Apple component. it would take the oranges property provided to it and take care of rendering the oranges.